# Create a matrix with headers and inserting values by calling the headers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it in python possible to create a zero-matrix with headers and insert values by calling column-header and row-headers? For example:

```
# A B C
d 0 0 0
e 0 0 0
f 0 0 0
```

the I write for example `matrix('A', 'd') = 1` and `matrix('B', 'e') = 3` and get

```
# A B C
d 1 0 0
e 0 3 0
f 0 0 0
```

And when I am done I want to be able to save it to csv.
Hope someone can help me, because I have not idea if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would come close to your need:

```
rows = dict((x,y) for y,x in enumerate('ABC')) # rows' headers
cols = dict((x,y) for y,x in enumerate('def')) # cols' headers

len_cols = 3
len_rows = 3
matrix = [[0 for i in range(len_cols)] for j in range(len_rows)]

def update(row, col, val):
    matrix[rows[row]][cols[col]] = val
```

**examples:**

```
>>> cols = dict((x,y) for y,x in enumerate('de'))
>>> rows = dict((x,y) for y,x in enumerate('ABCD'))
>>> len_cols = 2
>>> len_rows = 4
>>> matrix = [[0 for i in range(len_cols)] for j in range(len_rows)]

>>> update('B','e',1)
>>> update('D','d',3)
>>> matrix
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [3, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you Ayush Shanker. Very intresstig solution. I found numpy, it also should work with numpy or am I mistaken?

Comment: while it will work with numpy perfectly, numpy might have its own solution to this (which you would have to find yourself from the docs). Also you may mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.